# Set Spring Session Redis on production only

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session, spring-data-redis, spring-profiles

Is it possible to set the Spring session data redis module on `production` profile only?

I have tried using `@Profile` but the `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` was initialized before setting the `profile/environment` and thus will give me an NoSuchBean Exception

`NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' available`

And when I try to inject the profile using `@Values` it returns null value.

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active:local}")
private String activeProfile; // result is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem using [this article](https://sdqali.in/blog/2016/07/16/controlling-redis-auto-configuration-for-spring-boot-session/).

The production session config will be like this.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.profiles.active", havingValue = "production")
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "redis.db")
public class ProductionSessionConfig {

    @Setter
    private String server;
    @Setter
    private Integer port;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        //creates your own connection
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(server, port);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
    }

}
```

And if you are not going to use the `spring-session-data-redis` in other environment. You can just proceed. Just keep in mind the `@ConditionalOnProperty` value.

And do not forget to exclude the Auto Configuration of Session.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SessionAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot 3, there do not seem to be any configuration options to force the session handler. [Spring Boot follows a deterministic pattern to load specific session handlers from the class path](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.spring-session). This leaves us with 2 options:

1. Build our own session switcher (as demonstrated by [@Kerppag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54143855/850782)).
2. Apply conditional dependency management. With Gradle, consider this option:

```java
if (project.hasProperty('redis')) {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis'
}
```

When you are ready to build for production, define the property "redis" during the build. You may also change the conditional to look for an environment variable. This opens up a lot of possibilities.